# Sum of two numbers with bitwise operator

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am pasting the code to find the sum of two numbers with bitwise operator. Please suggest if it can be optimized. Thanks...

```
public static int getSum(int p, int q)
{
int carry=0, result =0;
for(int i=0; i<32; i++)
{
    int n1 = (p & (1<<(i)))>>(i); //find the nth bit of p
    int n2 = (q & (1<<(i)))>>(i); //find the nth bit of q

    int s = n1 ^ n2 ^ carry; //sum of bits
    carry = (carry==0) ? (n1&n2): (n1 | n2); //calculate the carry for next step
    result = result | (s<<(i)); //calculate resultant bit
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: Don't do this.  The JITter will optimize this for you already.

Comment: If it for education then why do you need optimization? Else DO NOT DO THIS! as @SLaks already said.

Comment: @SLaks can you please tell me whats this JITter. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Trying: I don't mean to sound rude, but if you don't know what the JIT is, you have no business doing low-level optimizations like this.  If you want to make your program run faster, make it do less work.  Writing code like this will not help and may hurt.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation

Comment: @SLaks i know it, but confused with the word JITter!!! But anyways thanks for your comment.

Comment: The standard answer is a lot simpler than this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068033/addition-of-two-integers-using-bitwise-operators

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Think in entire bits:

```
public static int getSum(int p, int q)
{
    int result = p ^ q; // + without carry 0+0=0, 0+1=1+0=1, 1+1=0
    int carry = (p & q) << 1; // 1+1=2
    if (carry != 0) {
        return getSum(result, carry);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This recursion ends, as the carry has consecutively more bits 0 at the right (at most 32 iterations).

One can easily write it as a loop with `p = result; q = carry;`.

Another feature in algorithmic exploration is not going too far in differentiating cases.
Above you could also take the condition: `if ((result & carry) != 0)`.

Comment: Didn't get, Why do you do left shift in line 4. Carry is (a AND b), isn't it?

Comment: @ShivendraMishra binary 1+1 = 10 = (1 and 1) shift left once. So a carry counts for the bit to the left. Or else: `x+y = (x^y) + ((x&y) << 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the optimizations should be in the field of readability, rather than performance (which will probably be handled by the compiler).

#### Use for loop instead of while

The idiom `for (int i=0; i<32; i++)` is more readable than the while loop if you know the number of iterations in advance.

#### Divide the numbers by two

Dividing the numbers by two and getting the modulu:

```
n1 = p % 2;
p  /= 2;
```

Is perhaps more readable than:

```
(p & (1<<(i-1)))>>(i-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below soln is easy to understand & simple,

```
public static void sumOfTwoNumberUsingBinaryOperation(int a,int b)
{
    int c = a&b;
    int r = a|b;
    while(c!=0)
    {
        r =r <<1;
        c = c >>1;      
    }
    System.out.println("Result:\t" + r);    
}
```