# Adding a two number without using + sign

Tags: c

I am 9 grade, My math teacher asked me to add numbers with out using `+` sign in C program.

I tried  `a - (-b) = a + b;` but my math teacher want some other option.

Comment: Your solution is the one I thought about first.

Comment: He probably means bitwise then? Off the top of my head: AND to spot bits that'll carry, XOR to add; then shift the AND result left and repeat adding that to the XOR value until there's no AND left?

Comment: Perhaps try something more... iterative.  ( think a `while` )

Comment: How about [Addition of two integers using bitwise operators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4068033/1168156) ?

Comment: Implement a full-adder.

Comment: You genius you thought this in the 9th grade!!

Comment: So how is Java related? Why is it tagged?

Comment: Wow, a nice question. I'm gonna learn much with this question

Comment: You should really ask your prof to be more specific on the constraints. The logarithm-based approach below is elegant, but seems a bit too "easy". I'm suspecting your prof, given that this is a programming course, wants you to use a boolean-logic based approach, rather than an algebraic approach. +1 to all the solutions below!

Comment: Although the question is rather interesting, this is asking to do his homework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `Anti Log()` you can do that

```
Temp= Anti Log(a)* Anti Log(b);

a+b value is equals to log(Temp);
```

Works for integers not for double.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: I like this logic. It worked for integers.

Comment: Difference its not exact equal. there is some difference after decimal point

Comment: for a-b = log(antilog(a)/antlog(b))


for a*b=log(antiLog(a)+antLog(b))


for a/b= log((antilog(a)-(antilog(b)))

Comment: @sarmachinta...I don't think your teacher expecting this solution to use Log. Better to use the one mentioned by vikas.

Comment: "Anti Log" is a pretty strange name, considering that logarithm _is itself defined as_ the inverse of exponentiation...

Answer (score 23):

Use this function in your c program

```
int Add(int a, int b)
{
    while (b)
    {
        // carry now contains common set bits of "a" and "b"
        int carry = a & b;

        // Sum of bits of "a" and "b" where at least one of the bits is not set
        a = a ^ b;

        // Carry is shifted by one so that adding it to "a" gives the required sum
        b = carry << 1;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Use bitwise `^` and `&` operators and recursion

```
int add(int x, int y){
    return y == 0 ? x : add( x ^ y, (x & y) << 1);
}
```

P.S.: It is the recursive version of an algorithm proposed by vikas.

Answer (score 8):

In Java using recursion-

```
public static int add(int a, int b){

    if(b == 0) return a;
    int sum = a ^ b;
    int carry = (a & b) << 1;

    return add(sum, carry);

}
```

In C-

```
int add(int a, int b){

    if(b == 0) return a;
    int sum = a ^ b;
    int carry = (a & b) << 1;

    return add(sum, carry);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b) {
    return (int)&((char *)a)[b];
}

int main() {
    printf("%d", add(5, 17));
    getchar();
}
```

Not portable but doesn't use the "+" character. This casts a to a char pointer, adds b to it with [] and then casts it back to an int.