# Truncate float to nearest power of 2 in C++ - Performance

Tags: c++, performance, floating-point

In C++ (presume at least C++11), given a floating point value a, I need to find the floating point value b satisfying the following constraints:

- b must have the same sign as a.
- The magnitude of b must be less-or-equal [*] to the magnitude of a.
- The magnitude of b must be a power of 2.
- THe magnitude of b must be as large as possible within these constraints.

In other words, I need to "truncate" the magnitude of a to the nearest power of 2, while leaving the sign unchanged.

[* The "less-or-equal" constraint is lax in my case, and "less" would also work.]

Given some IEEE 754 binary representation, one approach to achieving this 
would be to simply clear all mantissa bits via bit bashing, while leaving the sign and exponent bits unchanged.

A more portable approach would be to:

1. Get the base-2 logarithm of the magnitude, rounded down, using e.g. `logb`, `ilogb`, or even more portable, `log2` or `frexp`.
2. Raise 2 to the n-th power using e.g. integer bit shifting (beware negative powers and value range issues), `pow(2.0,n)`, `exp2(n)`, or `ldexp(1.0,n)`.
3. Copy the sign via `copysign`.

This allows for a lot of possible combinations to solve the task, even more so when also considering the single-precision alternatives. **Does anyone have any experience with these approaches regarding performance on modern hardware and using modern compilers?**

Comment: Remember that C and C++ are two *very* different languages, where even things that might be similar could have minute differences in wording in their respective specifications, making things work very differently from what might be expected. So unless you want to compare the two languages directly then please don't use both tags, and never use the term "C/C++".

Comment: I'd be surprised if C and C++ behave much different performance-wise with respect to these functions, so I'd expect answers from both C and C++ programmers to be relevant. But here you go - no more C, just C++.

Comment: @drescherjm I'd be interested in any observations you can share about the performance of the individual building blocks I mentioned, or combos thereof. For instance, to my amazement I'm just finding out that on my machine `ilogb(float)` is slower than `ilogbf(float)`, which in turn is slower still than converting to double and invoking `ilogb(double)`. Which makes no sense to me, but I can't deny the experimental evidence.

Answer (score 5):

Use `frexp()`<sup>1</sup>, `ldexp()`<sup>2</sup> to render `a` and form the answer.

These 2 functions are nearly exactly all that is needed.

> The `frexp` functions break a floating-point number into a normalized fraction and an integral power of 2.  ... `frexp` functions return the value `x`,
>   such that `x` has a magnitude in the interval [1/2, 1) or zero.
>
> The `ldexp` functions multiply a floating-point number by an integral power of 2.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double round_pow2(double a) {
  int exp;
  double frac = frexp(a, &exp);
  if (frac > 0.0) frac = 0.5;
  else if (frac < 0.0) frac = -0.5;
  double b = ldexp(frac, exp);

  printf("% 20g % 25a % 25a", a, a, b);
  printf(" %d", !!signbit(a) == !!signbit(b)); // b must have the same sign as a.
  printf(" %d\n", !(fabs(b) > fabs(a)));       // magnitude `b` must be <= magnitude `a`.

  return b;
}
```

Test code

```
void round_pow2_test(double x) {
  round_pow2(nextafter(-x, -INFINITY));
  round_pow2(-x);
  round_pow2(nextafter(-x, INFINITY));
  round_pow2(nextafter(x, -INFINITY));
  round_pow2(x);
  round_pow2(nextafter(x, INFINITY));
}

int main(void) {
  round_pow2_test(0);
  round_pow2_test(DBL_MIN);
  round_pow2_test(1.0);
  round_pow2_test(42.0);
  round_pow2_test(DBL_MAX);
  round_pow2(NAN);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
   -4.94066e-324                -0x1p-1074                -0x1p-1074 1 1
              -0                   -0x0p+0                   -0x0p+0 1 1
    4.94066e-324                 0x1p-1074                 0x1p-1074 1 1
   -4.94066e-324                -0x1p-1074                -0x1p-1074 1 1
               0                    0x0p+0                    0x0p+0 1 1
    4.94066e-324                 0x1p-1074                 0x1p-1074 1 1
   -2.22507e-308  -0x1.0000000000001p-1022                -0x1p-1022 1 1
   -2.22507e-308                -0x1p-1022                -0x1p-1022 1 1
   -2.22507e-308  -0x1.ffffffffffffep-1023                -0x1p-1023 1 1
    2.22507e-308   0x1.ffffffffffffep-1023                 0x1p-1023 1 1
    2.22507e-308                 0x1p-1022                 0x1p-1022 1 1
    2.22507e-308   0x1.0000000000001p-1022                 0x1p-1022 1 1
              -1     -0x1.0000000000001p+0                   -0x1p+0 1 1
              -1                   -0x1p+0                   -0x1p+0 1 1
              -1     -0x1.fffffffffffffp-1                   -0x1p-1 1 1
               1      0x1.fffffffffffffp-1                    0x1p-1 1 1
               1                    0x1p+0                    0x1p+0 1 1
               1      0x1.0000000000001p+0                    0x1p+0 1 1
             -42     -0x1.5000000000001p+5                   -0x1p+5 1 1
             -42                 -0x1.5p+5                   -0x1p+5 1 1
             -42     -0x1.4ffffffffffffp+5                   -0x1p+5 1 1
              42      0x1.4ffffffffffffp+5                    0x1p+5 1 1
              42                  0x1.5p+5                    0x1p+5 1 1
              42      0x1.5000000000001p+5                    0x1p+5 1 1
            -inf                      -inf                   -0x1p-1 1 1
   -1.79769e+308  -0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023                -0x1p+1023 1 1
   -1.79769e+308  -0x1.ffffffffffffep+1023                -0x1p+1023 1 1
    1.79769e+308   0x1.ffffffffffffep+1023                 0x1p+1023 1 1
    1.79769e+308   0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023                 0x1p+1023 1 1
             inf                       inf                    0x1p-1 1 1
             nan                       nan                       nan 1 1
```

---

<sup>1</sup> From OP's "Get the base-2 logarithm of the magnitude, rounded down, using e.g. ... frexp."

<sup>2</sup> From OP's "Raise 2 to the n-th power using e.g. ... ldexp(1.0,n)."

Comment: I'm aware of this. But do you have experience how it compares with the other possibilities performance-wise? (For instance, naively I would assume bit bashing to be an even faster approach for the truncate case, requiring just a single AND instruction - but then I have no idea how data transfer between AVX and main CPU registers might counteract that advantage.)

Comment: @ChristophLipka "Bit bashing" can be faster with a subset of `double`, yet _certainly_ slower  when the entire range of `double` must be handle correctly (AND will not do it) as the "bit bashing" user code then replicates the library `frexp, ldexp`.  On a select platform and library a `round2power2(x)` may already exist - but then that is not portable per the standard library.   If you truly want something "faster", you need to  code the performance rating tool (average of all x, worst case, ...), subset of `double` if that is allowed and target platform/compiler. The above is your baseline.

Comment: @ChristophLipka Tale care about posting a moving target question.  Once answers arrive, it is poor SO etiquette to change the goals (languages, general to platform specific, etc.)  It is good to elaborate, provide missing detail.  Be mindful the things others aware of are base on the question and not unwritten/unspecific intentions.

Comment: @ChristophLipka Note: "simply clear all mantissa bits" fails for sub-normals and NAN.  Those need other handling.  Depending on how bits are cleared for others values, code can run into anti-aliasing issues and certainly portability issues.  You could code up a solution **and** test harness and then ask for improvements: "how to make faster given certain conditions" - perhaps on here or [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ChristophLipka Lastly, my decades of experience point the optimization in narrow cases is far too often [pre-mature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).  Far better to 1) Start with a portably full range working solution and then 2) use  "tricks" only when demonstrably necessary. Better to use my programmer skills to improve overall system efficiency and not minor linear improvements as suggested here with a mask.

Comment: "it is poor SO etiquette to change the goals" No goals have been changed, except that I dropped reference to C at the suggestion of another SO user (superior in reputation). Question has _explicitly_ been about performance, not how-to, right from the start; I just retroactively applied emphasis after getting the impression that some readers were taking a TL;DR approach to reading questions, and missing this key detail.

Comment: @ChristophLipka: I am not surprised that chux was annoyed with you! After such a comprehensive and thoughtful answer, you say "I'm aware of this." Well why didn't you say so to start with? What a waste of chux's time! You should be apologising.

Comment: @TonyK Why? Because they failed to read my question to the end and thus their answer totally missed the point? (:shrugs:)

Comment: @ChristophLipka The question was read in its entirety and had various conflicting unclear issues.  As the author, it may have been clear to you yet the initial "I need to find the floating point value b satisfying the following constraints:" appeared  paramount and this answer focused on that.  Not the trailing "Does anyone have any experience with these approaches regarding performance on modern hardware and using modern compilers?".  The trailing question's  direct answer is : "yes, I do".   Best to put the most important aspect of your question first, not last .

Comment: @chux You mean, like, in the subject of the question?

Comment: @ChristophLipka Yes. Question lacked any performance benchmark details nor provided a baseline.  To rate performance, one needs a baseline as provided here. To consider alternatives, parameters of range of floating point needed (assumed full range), platform/complier (assumed generic,C99 compliant).  Example, to even [double a FP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54610832/2410359) value takes a fair amount of tests for the full range of  a floating point type.  "one approach to achieving this would be to simply clear all mantissa bits via bit bashing," is insufficient for this question's goal.

Comment: Technically, there is no solution if `a` is zero, since no `b` satisfies the constraints of the problem. If we do not care what is returned when `a` is zero, then `frac = copysign(.5, frac);` suffices and might perform better than the `if…else if…`.

Comment: Since I'm after a relative comparison between potentially vastly different approaches, I don't see the benefit of specifying a particular approach as a baseline. If anything at all, I'd exopect it to discourage people from posting their personal experience with approaches X and Y because I gave Z as the baseline which they happen to not have any experience with. Specifying a particular platform or compiler would also be counter-productive, as the project I'm working on is supposed to be portable (but choosing between alternative optimized implementations at compile time is an option).

Comment: @EricPostpischil From the tests I'm currently conducting, it seems that `ldexp((a<0?-0.5:0.5),exp)` will be faster than `kdexp(copysign(0.5,a),exp)`, and on par with `b=ldexp(0.5,exp); if(a<0) b=-b;` -- on my machine anyway. Which makes sense I think, because `copysign` must deal with arbitrary mantissas and exponents, while in this case the mantissa and exponent are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

From my own tests, I'm coming to the following conclusions so far (but since I don't have a test lab at my disposal, my observational evidence is limited, and the jury is still out):

- It is pretty irrelevant whether operations are performed in the single or double precision domain. As a matter of fact, most functions involved seem to perform slightly faster in their double precision incarnation, even when this requires additional conversions.
- The single precision functions without `f` suffix (e.g. `ilogb`) should be avoided, as they generally perform poorer than their `f` suffix counterparts (e.g. `ilogbf`).
- "bit bashing" is unrivaled in terms of performance. Surprisingly, this also performs better in the 64-bit domain (then again, I'm testing on a 64-bit machine). I'm seeing less than 1 ns per execution. By comparison, my "testbed" itself weighs in at about 15 ns per iteration.

As for implementations of the "pow2(floor(log2))" approach, here's what I'm concluding so far:

- I don't see any special *combination* of the basic building blocks that would give a performance boost from unexpected synergy effects, so it seems reasonable to consider the types of building blocks ("pow2", "floor(log2)" and sign fix) separately.
- Presuming the 0.0 case is of little concern, the fastest way to handle sign is to essentially do a "pow2(floor(log2(abs)))" operation, then fix the sign with a simple `if(a<0) b=-b;`, being about 5 ns faster than `copysign`. If the "pow2" building block has a mantissa-like factor (like `ldexp` does), using a comparison to choose between a positive or negative factor is also a viable option, being only slightly slower than the post-operation conditional fix.
- By far the worst choice for the "pow2" operation (and one which the software I'm working on has been using for ages in two implementations) is to naively use `pow(2.0,x)`. While a compiler could conceivably optimize it into something much faster, mine doesn't. `exp2` is about 60 ns faster. `ldexp` is another 15 ns faster still, making it the best choice, weighing in at a guesstimated 8-10 ns.
- There is an even faster option (also used in the software I'm working on), namely using bit shifts in the integer domain, but it comes at the cost of severely restricting the range of values for which the function works. If this road is to be ventured, the operation should be performed in the `long long` domain, as it's only marginally slower than in the `int` domain. This approach may save another 4-5 ns.
- The slowest "floor(log2)" building block I could find (aside from `(int)(log(x)/log(2))`, which I didn't even bother to test) was `(int)log2(fabs(x))` and their kin. `frexp` is about 30 ns faster, weighing in at a guesstimated 8-10 ns.
- If the floating-point type uses a base-2 representation, `ilogb` is a viable alternative to `frexp` and saves another 1 ns. `logb` is slightly slower than `ilogb` (on par with `frexp`), which makes sense I guess.

---

All in all, so far the following implementations seem worth considering:

```
double Pow2Trunc(double a)
{
    union { double f; uint64_t i; } hack;
    hack.f = a;
    hack.i &= 0xFFF0000000000000u;
    return hack.f;
}
```

being the fastest implementation (ca. 1 ns), provided special values are of no concern, the float binary format is known (in this case IEEE binary64), and an int type of same size and byte ordering is available;

```
double Pow2Trunc(double a)
{
    int exp;
    (void)frexp(a,&exp);
    double b = ldexp(0.5, exp);
    if (a < 0) b = -b;
    return b;
}
```

being the fastest fully portable implementation (ca. 16 ns); and maybe

```
double Pow2Trunc(double a)
{
    double b = ldexp(1.0, ilogb(a));
    if (a < 0) b = -b;
    return b;
}
```

being a slightly less portable but also slightly faster alternative (ca. 15 ns).

(Handling of special values can presumably be improved; for my use case however they do not matter enough to warrant further examination.)

Providing alternaties based on `float` does not seem to be worth the effort; if they are provided, it is important to use the `f`-suffixed variants of the functions.

---

Obviously these results are subject to hardware platform, compiler and settings (i7-5820K, Windows 10 Subsystem for Linux, g++ 5.4.0, `-std=gnu++11 -o3 -ffast-math`). Other environments' mileage may vary, and **learning about cases where the results are qualitatively different would be most valuable to me**.