# What is the use of bit manipulation?

Tags: image-processing, compression, bit-manipulation

I searched for clear explanation with some example close to real life.

What is bit manipulation?

Why we need to use bit manipulation?

We can use bit manipulation in image processing as far as I know. Can anyone show me a simple problem which can be solved using bit manipulation?

I read about bit manipulation from some link:

[Link 1](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/bit-manipulation/basics-of-bit-manipulation/tutorial/)

[Link 2](https://www.kinematicsoup.com/news/2016/9/6/data-compression-bit-packing-101)

In Link 2 Data compression is done using bit packing. Are there any difference between bit manipulation and bit packing?

It will be appreciable If anyone explain me with very simple example which have resemble to real life problem.

Answer (score 3):

**What is bit manipulation?**

Bit manipulation usually refers to changing data using bit operators.

I think Wikipedia expains it good enough so I won't write another article.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation

> Bit manipulation is the act of algorithmically manipulating bits or
> other pieces of data shorter than a word. Computer programming tasks
> that require bit manipulation include low-level device control, error
> detection and correction algorithms, data compression, encryption
> algorithms, and optimization. For most other tasks, modern programming
> languages allow the programmer to work directly with abstractions
> instead of bits that represent those abstractions. Source code that
> does bit manipulation makes use of the bitwise operations: AND, OR,
> XOR, NOT, and possibly other operations analogous to the boolean
> operators; there are also bit shifts and operations to count ones and
> zeros, find high and low one or zero, set, reset and test bits,
> extract and insert fields, mask and zero fields, gather and scatter
> bits to and from specified bit positions or fields. Integer arithmetic
> operators can also effect bit-operations in conjunction with the other
> operators.
>
> Bit manipulation, in some cases, can obviate or reduce the need to
> loop over a data structure and can give many-fold speed ups, as bit
> manipulations are processed in parallel.

**Why we need to use bit manipulation?**

Because it is fast and often we don't have another choice. For example in microcontrollers, pretty much everything is controlled by manipulating the bits of 8 bit registers. So an output would go high if you set a certain bit 1.

Bit packing is a compression technique that tries to minimize the number of bits necessary to represent a number. While you'll use bit operators to implement it, it is not the same as "bit-manipulation". It's just one of many many use cases for bit-manipulation.

**Can anyone show me a simple problem which can be solved using bit manipulation?**

Let's say you have a rgb touple `rgb = 0xa1fc03` and you want to make the green channel 0.

`rgb_without_green = rgb & 0xFF00FF`

We've bitwise `AND`ed the value with `0xFF00FF`.

Now `rgb` is `0xa10003`.

Basically any operation boils down to bit manipulation. For most of them you just have convenient solutions. Say instead of `0x00000011 << 0x0000101` you write `3 * 32`

Or have a look at this where the addition of two integers is implemented using bit operations. [Add two integers using only bitwise operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068033/add-two-integers-using-only-bitwise-operators)

## Edit due to comment

> How bitwise AND operation between 0xa1fc03 and 0xFF00FF gives 0xa10003
> ? Just I need to see how to do this calculation

Bitwise `AND` means that you `AND` all the bits of both numbers.

```
1 AND 1 -> 1
0 AND 1 -> 0
1 AND 0 -> 0
0 AND 0 -> 0
```

So

```
0xa1fc03 -> 0b101000011111110000000011
0xff00ff -> 0b111111110000000011111111
AND ->      0b101000010000000000000011

0b101000010000000000000011 -> 0xa10003
```

With a bit more expierience you know that `0xFF` is `0b11111111` so you instantly know that `0xa1fc03 AND 0xff00ff`  is `0xa1003` becaue you keep everything that is masked with FF and set everything 0 that is masked with 00.

There are countless resources available. You should not have to ask me how to bitwise AND two numbers. Please do your own research.

Comment: what is touple?

Comment: bitwise AND operation between 0xa1fc03 and 0xFF00FF gives 0xa10003 ? Can you explain more simply how you do calculations here?

Comment: @zipperblock sorry I meant tuple, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple

I don't understand your second comment. what should I say? yes?

Comment: How bitwise AND operation between 0xa1fc03 and 0xFF00FF gives 0xa10003 ? Just I need to see how to do this calculation

Answer (score 0):

I am busy designing a new barcode symbology for real-life applications. It uses a checksum value, which is computed on slices of `k` bits of large numbers. Hence intense bit manipulation.