How to turn a 16-bit number in one's complement into it's 7-segment display equivalence?
I have a 16-bit integer, in one's complement, and I'm trying to retrieve it's 7-seg display equivalence. Using only bitwise operations.
I'm doing it for a Minecraft project/hobby, just trying to build a full adder with negative operands.
I want the resulting integer to be transformed from a 16 bit integer, to a 5 digit 7-segment display, like this: 
I understand logic gates but am a beginner in computer logic, so if you can explain me in the simplest terms or maybe programatically, like using Java or Python, it'd be better.
Actually, I don't know a bit of how to do it, I tried to search for answers and ask AI, but didn't got any plausible answer. I need something that uses only bitwise operations, and to be explained using them, if possible. I'm a begginer in computer theory. If you can explain me step-by-step and/or using simple terms, I'd be grateful.

Use "1,2,4,8,...,till 16384"to represent each bit and last bit to represent sign.You still need to design redstone circuits for bitwise add operations.Referring to this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068033/add-two-integers-using-only-bitwise-operators

@AmadeuszLiu I know how to do the sum and the circuits for the full adders are already there. I want to know how to transform the result in a 7-segment display decimal.

@life888888 I'mma do it, thanks for the suggestion.

As far as I can tell, you want the result to be displayed in decimal. So, this comment assumes that. First, you would want to convert from one's complement to decimal. If you want help with that part, you should tell us how the one's complement number is represented. Is it a String? byte []? char[]? What? (If you don't need help converting it to decimal, it doesn't have to be part of the question.)  Second, you would need a simulation of 7-segment display. What are you using for that? Is it code you created yourself? If so, did you use Swing? JavaFX? What?

For reference, the O/P did ask "How to convert a 16-bit binary number to a signed integer in Java". That question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78666255/how-to-convert-a-16-bit-binary-number-to-a-signed-integer-in-java

The question should show some code. That would make what you are asking more understandable. These resources, and pages they link to might help you edit the question: Take the Tour, How to Write a Good Question, Other pages linked to from the Help Center, and Minimal Reproducible Example.

@OldDogProgrammer The thing is, I don't have no code. I just asked for an explanation that I could implement in Minecraft. All answers AI gave me wasn't that clear and easy to follow steps.

@life888888 That part of 0111... -> 32767 and 1111... -> -1, I already know. I just need a way to turn that one's complement number in a seven segment display representation. Better yet, if you can only explain me how binary to BCD conversion work, it'd already be sufficient.

Note that 1111.. -> -1 is in two's complement, in ones' complement 1111.. -> -0 (negative zero being distinct from positive zero in ones' complement, although sometimes some normalization is used to every -0 into the normal 0). Are you really using ones' complement? It's unusual and requires a small modification to adders to make them work (a "bare" unsigned adder is also a two's complement adder, a ones' complement adder needs end-around carry)

"The thing is, I don't have no code" Then, there might be a misunderstanding about how Stack Overflow is intended to be used. If you need lessons, Stack Overflow is the wrong place, as it is not a tutorial service.

In a comment, the O/P said "... Better yet, if you can only explain how binary to BCD conversion work, it'd already be sufficient."
So, this answer will be mostly about converting to BCD. Converting a number to a seven segment display limited to bitwise operations is more than I care to get into.
BCD (Binary Coded Decimal) is simply any representation of a number such that, when the number is expressed in base ten, each digit is represented in binary.
Suppose I have 27 (decimal). In binary, that is 11011. If it is coded in BCD, the bits would look like this: 0010 0111. Note that 0010 is 2 in decimal, representing the first digit, and 0111 is 7 in decimal, representing the second digit.
BCD uses 4 bits, or one nybble, for each digit. The storage units used are up to the developer. The developer could choose to have 1 byte, short, or int for each digit. Or, two digits might be stored in each byte. Or, 4 digits might be stored in each short. Or, 8 digits might be stored in each int.
Here is a method that converts an integer to BCD with 8 digits in an int return type. There is no provision allowing for a sign:
public static int bcd8Pack (int n) {
   int packed = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
      int digit = n % 10;
      n /= 10;
      int place = digit << (i * 4);
      packed = packed | place;
   }
   return packed;
}

Example use:
System.out.println (Integer.toUnsignedString (bcd8Pack (98_765_432),16));`

Output: 98765432
Let us suppose we have a class with an instance field private final byte [] bcd; . It might convert an int to BCD with one digit per byte:
public void set (int n) {
   int m = Math.abs (n);
   for (int i = bcd.length - 1 ; i >= 1 ; --i ) {
      bcd [i] = (byte) (m % 10);
      m /= 10;
   }
   bcd [0] = (byte) ( n < 0 ? MINUS_FLAG : PLUS_FLAG );        
}

This assumes element [0] has been reserved for a sign, which may have one of two values (MINUS_FLAG or PLUS_FLAG).
For converting a decimal digit to a 7 segment display, we want to convert the digit into a binary number such that each bit corresponds to one segment. The bit to segment matching can be arbitrary. A "map" is in the code below. For the conversion, instead of using bitwise operations, I would use a translation table.
The code below includes a simulation of a 7-segment display using a low resolution 7 x 5 dot-matrix format. The code uses a 7 x 7 dot-matrix because I reserved the left and right columns for spacing. The dot matrix output is there only to test the translation table approach.
public class DigitalDisplay {
    
    /*  Seven segment map:
     *       -5-
     *      |   |
     *      4   0
     *      |   |
     *       -6- 
     *      |   |
     *      3   1
     *      |   |
     *       -2- 
    */
    
    /*  0123456
          ***   0
         *   *  1
         *   *  2
          ***   3
         *   *  4
         *   *  5
          ***   6
    */
    
    private static final byte MINUS_FLAG = 0xd; 
    private static final byte PLUS_FLAG = 0xc; 
    public  static final char SPACE = ' ';
    public  static final char ON = '*';
    
    private final byte [] bcd;
    
    static class Digit {
        
        private static final byte [] translate = {
              0b00111111, 0b00000011, 0b01101101, 0b01100111, 0b01010011 
            , 0b01110110, 0b01111110, 0b00110011, 0b01111111, 0b01110111  };
        private static final byte MINUS_SIGN =  0b01000000;
        private static final byte PLUS_SIGN = 0;
 
        char [][] display;
        
        Digit () {
            setEmpty ();            
        }
        
        /* value is from 0 to 9 or 12 or 13. 
                  12 represents a plus sign. 13 represents a minus sign 
        */
        Digit (byte value) {  
            setEmpty ();  
            byte register; 
            switch (value)  {
                case MINUS_FLAG:
                    register = MINUS_SIGN;
                    break;
                case PLUS_FLAG:
                    register = PLUS_SIGN;
                    break;
                default:
                    register = translate [value];
                    break;                                
            } // end switch (value)
            if ((register & 0b1) == 1) {   // segment 0
                display [1][5] = ON;
                display [2][5] = ON;
            }
            if ((register & 0b10) == 2) {  // segment 1
                display [4][5] = ON;
                display [5][5] = ON;                
            }
            if ((register & 0b100) == 4) {  // segment 2
                display [6][2] = ON;
                display [6][3] = ON;
                display [6][4] = ON;
            }
            if ((register & 0b1000) == 8) { // segment 3
                display [4][1] = ON;
                display [5][1] = ON;                
            }
            if ((register & 0b1_0000) == 16 ) { // segment 4
                display [1][1] = ON;
                display [2][1] = ON;
            }
            if ((register & 0b10_0000) == 32) { // segment 5
                display [0][2] = ON;
                display [0][3] = ON;
                display [0][4] = ON;
            }
            if ((register & 0b100_0000) == 64) { // segment 6
                display [3][2] = ON;
                display [3][3] = ON;
                display [3][4] = ON;
            }
        }
        private void setEmpty () {
            display = new char [7][7];
            for (int i = 0; i < display.length; ++i) {
                Arrays.fill (display [i], SPACE);
            }
        }
    } // end class Digit 
    
    
    
    public DigitalDisplay () {
        bcd = new byte [6]; // default size = 5 digits and 1 sign
    }
    
    public DigitalDisplay (int numDigits) {
        bcd = new byte [numDigits + 1]; // alow an extra for the sign
    }
    
    public void set (int n) {
        int m = Math.abs (n);
        for (int i = bcd.length - 1 ; i >= 1 ; --i ) {
            bcd [i] = (byte) (m % 10);
            m /= 10;
        }
        bcd [0] = (byte) ( n < 0 ? MINUS_FLAG : PLUS_FLAG );        
    }
       
    public String[] display () {
        Digit [] displayDigit = new Digit [bcd.length];
        for (int i = 0; i <  displayDigit.length; ++i) {
            displayDigit [i] = new Digit (bcd[i]);
        }
        
        String [] theDisplay = new String [displayDigit[1].display.length];
        StringBuilder [] displayNumber =
                new StringBuilder [displayDigit[1].display.length]; 
        for (int lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < displayNumber.length; ++lineIndex) {
            displayNumber [lineIndex]  = new StringBuilder 
                         (bcd.length * displayDigit[1].display[0].length);
            for (int  digitIndex = 0
                    ; digitIndex < displayDigit.length
                    ; ++digitIndex) {
                for (int digitColumnIndex = 0; 
                    digitColumnIndex < displayDigit[digitIndex].display.length; 
                    ++digitColumnIndex) {
                    displayNumber[lineIndex]
                       .append (displayDigit[digitIndex]
                               .display[lineIndex][digitColumnIndex]);     
                }
            }
            theDisplay [lineIndex] = displayNumber[lineIndex].toString();
        }
               
        return theDisplay;         
    }
    
    public static void print (DigitalDisplay disp) {
        String [] out = disp.display ();
        for (int i = 0; i < out.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println (out[i]);
        } 
        System.out.println ("\n\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        DigitalDisplay tenDigits = new DigitalDisplay (10);
        tenDigits.set (-1234567890);
        print (tenDigits);
        DigitalDisplay fiveDigits = new DigitalDisplay (5);
        fiveDigits.set (1234567);
        print (fiveDigits);
    }    
}


Output:
:
98765432
                ***    ***           ***    ***    ***    ***    ***    ***  
            *      *      *  *   *  *      *      *   *  *   *  *   *  *   * 
            *      *      *  *   *  *      *      *   *  *   *  *   *  *   * 
  ***           ***    ***    ***    ***    ***           ***    ***         
            *  *          *      *      *  *   *      *  *   *      *  *   * 
            *  *          *      *      *  *   *      *  *   *      *  *   * 
                ***    ***           ***    ***           ***    ***    ***  



         ***           ***    ***    ***  
            *  *   *  *      *      *   * 
            *  *   *  *      *      *   * 
         ***    ***    ***    ***         
            *      *      *  *   *      * 
            *      *      *  *   *      * 
         ***           ***    ***         

If there were a real 7-segment display, the value of register would be passed to an area tied to the display. The if ((register & ... statements are present only to set the values in the dot-matrix simulation.
Perhaps someone can edit this answer to replace the dot-matrix simulation with Swing or other graphics.
Note that this answer does not address one's-complement and two's complement.

This was a very good answer, thank you so much for the effort.
